# Use jQuery to Disable All Controls Then Set Them Back The Way They Were

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm having trouble with ASP.Net and Ajax, and controlling the enabling/disabling of controls.

I need a way to keep the attr disabled state of the controls somehow, because during a partial page postback I am disabling all the controls in jquery that cause a postback and then enabling them.

However some of the controls I'm disabling are in a repeater, which complicates the efforts.

So my question, is it possible to disable all controls on a page client side through jquery on beginrequest, and then set them back to the way they were with jquery on endrequest?

Comment: `.prop('disabled')`, not `.attr('disabled')`

Comment: Sounds like you have not put in enough effort especially when it comes to doing a google search.. try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324390/disabling-all-the-page-control-through-jquery

Comment: honestly have, I had a hard time formulating the question.  The link doesn't really help.  See some controls are disabled on the server side for a reason, and I don't want the jquery code to over ride it.  So I'm hoping to track the disabled state of each control, before the partial page postback, and setting them back the way they were.  What really confuses me is how to handle that problem within a repeater, which is my exact situation.

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to utilize the following code snippet to execute javascript or jQuery code after any .Net code executes:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "uniqueName", "<script type='text/javascript'>myJavascriptFunction();</script>");
```